# for Loop Syntactical Error?

Tags: objective-c, ios, for-loop, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an NSMutableArray that I'm looping through and attempting to find the average of every set of four and setting the average to the index that is the first value in that set. Here's what I've got:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < [romArray count] - 4; i++) {
        double a = [[romArray objectAtIndex:i] getValue] + [[romArray objectAtIndex:i+1] getValue] + [[romArray objectAtIndex:i + 2] getValue] + [[romArray objectAtIndex:i + 3] getValue];
        a /= 4;
        [romArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[[Value alloc] initWithValues:[[romArray objectAtIndex:i] getTimestamp]  :a ]];
        [romArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(i + 1, 3)]];
        b++;
    }

    NSLog(@"%i", b);
```

`b` is returned as 70, (of a set of 280 something) so I know the issue isn't in the `i++`. When the loop is through, there are still the same number of objects in the array, so the `removeObjects` method isn't *actually* removing the objects. Ideas as to why not?

Comment: First of all its always a bad idea to mutate the object that you are enumerating. Why don't you create a second array to store your average values?

Comment: @Alladinian why's it a bad idea? I do it all the time.

Comment: One really bold example of why its a bad idea can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554430/objective-c-2-0-and-fast-enumeration-throwing-exceptions)

Answer (score -1):

1)Can you post some more code? NSMutable array hasn't "getValue" method.

2)If your code is workable then I try for example this array { @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6" }. Count = 6. Loop will make 2 operations with deleting. After first it will be array { @"1", @"5", @"6" }. So the second operation would finish the program with an error or you will get an array { @"1", @"5" }. Is it correct?

Comment: `getValue` is a method of the Value class which is the object type of the objects of the array.

Comment: I can't understand you. Your code doesn't work in my version of sdk because of this problem

Comment: It has nothing to do with your SDK, you just do not have the `Value` class.