# iOS Crash - Collection mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, reachability

Application Specific Information:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFArray: 0x1f03a140> was mutated while being enumerated.'

```
Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x329a83e7 -[NSException encodeWithCoder:] + 218
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3a6a3963 +[Protocol load] + 22070
2   CoreFoundation                      0x329a7ec1 -[NSException name] + 0
3   Foundation                          0x33361e0f -[NSISLinearExpression enumerateVariables:] + 118
4   Foundation                          0x33359a5b -[NSISEngine removeRowWithHead:] + 142
5   Foundation                          0x3335a61f -[NSISEngine pivotToMakeBodyVar:newHeadOfRowWithHead:] + 174
6   Foundation                          0x3335e891 -[NSISEngine removeConstraintWithMarker:] + 280
7   Foundation                          0x33366eab -[NSLayoutConstraint _removeFromEngine:] + 230
8   UIKit                               0x34bf6bcd -[UIView _removeRelevantConstraintsFromEngine:] + 408
9   Foundation                          0x3335d997 -[NSISEngine withAutomaticOptimizationDisabled:] + 166
10  UIKit                               0x34bf6a95 -[UIView _removeRelevantConstraintsFromEngine:] + 96
11  UIKit                               0x3499ce55 -[UIView _willRemoveSubviewWantingAutolayout:] + 840
12  UIKit                               0x347e58d5 -[UIView removeFromSuperview] + 56
13  UIKit                               0x34835f41 -[UINavigationTransitionView _cleanupTransition] + 92
14  UIKit                               0x347ccabb -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 158
15  UIKit                               0x348418fd -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 48
16  QuartzCore                          0x34578309 -[CALayer dealloc] + 1240
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3aabd5db 0x3aabc000 + 5595
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3aac0e45 -[OS_object _dispose] + 11552
19  CoreFoundation                      0x3297c1b1 +[__NSCFLocale automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:] + 12368
20  CoreFoundation                      0x328ef23d -[__NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + 500
21  CoreFoundation                      0x328ef0c9 -[__NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + 128
22  GraphicsServices                    0x364ce33b 0x364c9000 + 21307
23  UIKit                               0x3480b2b9 +[UIImage kitImageNamed:] + 1128
24  MyApplication                       0x0009c78b -[Reachability currentReachabilityStatus] + 226
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x3aad0b20 0x3aacf000 + 6944
```

I have used the Reachability API at quite a few locations in my application but this with this stack trace I can't seem to figure out where the error has occured!!

Can someone please point me in the right direction ?

Comment: hows your array are look like ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554430/objective-c-2-0-and-fast-enumeration-throwing-exceptions and http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/how-to-solve-array-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated-exception/

Comment: can you share code..? check this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458786/collection-nsarraym-0x76c11b0-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated

Comment: looks like you're traversing an array a view's subviews and one of them is removed in the meantime.